# Resample 8KHz audio sample rate to 44.1KHz using swr_convert[FFMPEG]

Tags: c++, qt, audio, ffmpeg, core-audio

Anybody, has tried upsampling audio stream from 8K to 44.1K?

I need to resample input audio stream 8KHz to 44.1K since Mac OSX default audio output device support minimum 44.1K audio sampling rate.

I tried to up-sampling using FFMPEG swr_convert() API, it converts with lots of noise. Which is not good.
If anybody has tried successfully upscale 8K to 44.1 or 48K then please share it.

Solution with C/C++ library code is preferable. Didn't tried Core-audio samples.

I Tried swr_convert() code from following link https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/group__lswr.html#details

Thanks,
Ramanand

Comment: 8 kHz isn't a good quality to start with, but still the conversion shouldn't add _extra_ noise. You have verified that it's _extra_ noise, have you, not just low quality input?

Comment: does FFmpeg do it at all?

Comment: @rogerdpack: Yes FFMPEG swresample library does the conversion but not efficient.

Comment: @MSalters: I have verified in Audacity application that extra bits of data is just 'noise'. However, there is valid audio in between though.  I would like to know is it theoretically possible to up-sample 8K to 44.1K? with 16-bit signed int sample type.? Anybody could confirm that for me.

Comment: I'm not that convinced about your Audacity claim if you then continue to wonder whether upsampling is possible. The latter statement shows you're missing a background in signal processing, and terminology such as "extra bits" and "in between" reaffirms that.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes I very novice in signal processing and it's terminology. I just reported what I was hearing through audacity. I need to quickly do this job up-sampling or at least wanted to know is it theoretical possible to do or not? As per your point up view upsampling from 8K to 44.1K is possible though FFMPEG right?